# AspNetSqlMembershipProvider is used instead of ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider in mvc 4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to implement a simple AD authentication in mvc 4 application. Here is what I changed in web.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://test.com:636/DC=test,DC=com"/>
</connectionStrings>
...
<membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"/>
      </providers>
```

Here is a method from my service class which is using AD authentification:

```
public bool Authentificate(string userName, string password)
{
     var membershipSection = (MembershipSection)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/membership");

     string defaultProvider = membershipSection.DefaultProvider;

     MembershipProvider provider = Membership.Providers[defaultProvider];

     return provider != null && provider.ValidateUser(userName, password);
}
```

But when I debug my application I see that 'defaultProvider' is 'AspNetSqlMembershipProvider' instead of 'ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider' and the authentication is failed with message:

> Unable to connect to SQL Server database.    at
>   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server,
>   String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String
>   connectionString)    at
>   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.SetupApplicationServices(String
>   server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String
>   connectionString, String database, String dbFileName, SqlFeatures
>   features, Boolean install)    at
>   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String
>   fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString)

What's wrong here?

Comment: Seems that for some reason configuration is loaded not from web.config, but from machine.config file. Can you share some info about structure of your solution? Where is this service class defined, and how and where is it called?

Comment: @Andrei Hello! I have a following solution structure (6 projects):

**MyProject.Data  MyProject.Domain  MyProject.Infrastructure  MyProject.Presentation  MyProject.Tests  MyProject.Web**  **web.config** is located in .Web project root.  Service class with **Authentificate()** method is located in **.Domain** project. This method is called from controller class in **.Presentation** project. And controller is using view from **.Web project.  I can add any additional info if needed.

Comment: Where is the entry point of the application? Is it within **.Web** or **.Presentation** project, or maybe elsewhere?

Comment: @Andrei In .Presentation, class Application, method:     **protected void Application_Start()
        {
            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }**

Answer (score 0):

When a .Net application is started, it sets up domain settings from the corresponding config file. For web apps running on IIS, this is `web.condig`, for executables - `app.config` which is actually renamed into `executable_name.exe.config`. If no such file is found - settings from `machine.config` are being picked up. Important point here is that all assemblies within one domain are using same settings - those associated with entry point assembly. And no other settings are considered!

In your case, even though **Web** project has a `web.config` file, entry point is the `Presentation` project, so essentially `web.config` settings are not used in any way. The easiest fix here is to define `app.config` for **Presentation** project and have all necessary settings (like providers) inside it.

Comment: I added the same web.config to both .Presentation and .Domain projects but nothing changed ( I get the same exception.

Comment: @user2598794, have you added `web.config`, or `app.config`? `web.config` is only for web projects, while `app.config` is for executables (also note that `app.config` is renamed after build, so in output directory you will have something like `myproject.presentation.exe.config`).

Comment: @user2598794, then I must admit I need more info. What is the `Presentation` project? Is it executable, or dll, or anything else? How is it run?

Comment: All projects are 'ClassLibrary', I run them as usual: Ctrl-F5.

Comment: @user2598794, at least one of them (Presentation most likely) should be Console Application, otherwise there is nothing to run.

Comment: @user2598794, also make sure that config file shows up in the output directory.